# Fit a blanket to a person

Tags: modifiers

I have a model of a person exported from the MakeHuman software. I also do have a model of a blanket. What I want to do now, is to fit the blanket to the human, as if the human was sleeping under the blanket.
I have done some research and believe that the shrinkwarp modifier applied to the blanket with target "testHuman" should do the trick. However, the following happens:

1. The blanket seems too small when I apply the shrinkwarp modifier and is very weirdly shaped
2. When I increase the offset to about one, the blanket increases to a size which looks about right. When I decrease the offset again, the blanket shrinks again.

I believe, that this has also to do with the model for the human I use. I cannot really choose the whole human as a target, but only parts of it. I will attach some pictures to illustrate.
Can somebody explain to me the behavior occuring when I change the offset? Also, how can I use my human-model for this purpose?

[image: The two models I use]
[image: Parts of the human model]
[image: When shrinkwarp modifier applied with offset zero]
[image: When shrinkwarp modifier applied with offset one]

Comment: Why not cloth sim? Shrinkwrap way will be very tedious to get reasonable result.

Comment: Thats actually a good hint and a much better approach to the problem, I believe. This tutorial helped me to get what you were refering to: http://cgcookie.com/blender/2010/08/17/cloth-simulation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simplest way, using Cloth Simulator defaults.

Select body, then in Physics tab, select Collision:
[image: Select body, then in Physics tab select Collision]

Add Plane mesh, set smooth, then in Edit Mode, scale to cover body and subdivide it to desired level of billow detail. Select Cloth in the Physics tab:
[image: Add Plane mesh, set smooth, then in Edit Mode, scale to cover body and subdivide it to desired level of billow detail. Select Cloth in the Physics tab]

Raise Plane above all parts, then press Alt-A to begin simulation:
[image: Raise Plane above all parts]

Pick your favorite frame:
[image: Pick your favorite frame]

Comment: Thanks, thats how I will end up doing it. However, do you have an idea why the blanket begins to tear apart the closer it comes to the person? Is there a setting which prevents my cloth to get holes?

Comment: The degree of tearing mostly comes down to mesh resolution at the points of contact for both objects. More is better, but you will still get some. But this thread gives some great approaches to eliminating them: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?242001-CLOTH-SIM-how-to-reduce-or-prevent-tears-in-the-fabric

Comment: You could also add a solidify modifier *after the cloth in the modifier stack*.  That would make it look more realistic and as long as the blanket has a reasonable amount of subdivisions you shouldn't be able to see any of the body mesh poking through.